# Solving the inhomogeneous wave equation, with the Fourier transform

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following differential equation:
$$
\square \phi (t, \mathbf r) = 4\pi \delta^3(\mathbf r)
$$
Using the Fourier Transform,
$$
\mathcal F\{ \square \phi - 4\pi \delta^3(\mathbf r) \} =0 
$$
We get:
$$
\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2 \Phi}{\partial^2t} + k^2 \Phi = 4 \pi
$$
Solving:
$$
\Phi(t, \mathbf k) = A(\mathbf  k)e^{ic|k|t} + B(\mathbf  k)e^{-ic|k|t} + \frac{4\pi}{k^2}\\ \; \\ \; \\
\phi(t, \mathbf r) = \int_{\mathbb R^3} d^3\mathbf k \; e^{i \mathbf k\cdot\mathbf r} \left [A(\mathbf  k)e^{ic|k|t} + B(\mathbf  k)e^{-ic|k|t} + \frac{4\pi}{k^2} \right] 
$$
But I'm stuck, how I'm supposed to follow and find $\phi(t, \mathbf r)$ purely in terms of $t$ and $\mathbf r$. How can I solve the integral?

Comment: You might see what the initial conditions require.

Comment: This really comes down to solving an ODE; to find A(k) and B(k), use the initial conditions. Once you find them, the integral isn’t easy to compute. Kirchoff’s formula (in physical space) might be more enlightening.

Comment: Are you trying to rederive Green's function for the d'Alembertian ? If so, the source term on the right-hand side lacks a factor $\delta(t)$.